# Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

When I'm running this code, I'm getting error

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
for (var i = 9; i + 2 < lines.Length; i += 3)
        {
            Items.Add(new ItemProperties { 
                Item = lines[i],
                Description = lines[i + 1],
                Quantity = lines[i + 2],
                UnitPrice = lines[i + 3]

            });
        }
```

Can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: Well, what is the length of your array? Are you sure you meant `var i = 9`?

Comment: Yes, because there are others that uses `var i` = 1- 8

Comment: Ok, what is the total length of your array? Are you sure `i + 3` will not be out of bounds for your array length?

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, it should be `i += 4`. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `lines[i + 3]` in the loop, but your check only ensures that `i + 2` is in range - and the fact that you're using *4* values in the loop rather than 4 makes it look like this should probably be:

```
for (var i = 12; i + 3 < lines.Length; i += 4)
{
    Items.Add(new ItemProperties { 
        Item = lines[i],
        Description = lines[i + 1],
        Quantity = lines[i + 2],
        UnitPrice = lines[i + 3]
    });
}
```

(That's assuming you want to start on the 4th item, as before - you should check what you want the initial value of `i` to be.)